# Welcome message in a specific channel when a user joins the server. (guildMemberAdd, discord.js)

Tags: discord.js, bots, member

How do I make it so that my bot sends a message in a specific channel when a user joins?

When I do this, it logs nothing: [(Also here are my bot settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciwVL.png)

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Cloud Shield has been activated.")
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
    console.log(member);
});

client.login(process.env.token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not requesting the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"] });
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Cloud Shield has been activated.")
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
    console.log(member);
});

client.login(process.env.token)
```